# Android Setting text from a getter method in another class

Tags: android, class, getter

I've looked all over the place and taken all of the tips given, but my app still force closes.
The app has two classes (Main and Next) and "Next" class has a get method. When I try to use the get method in the "Main" class my app force closes. This is the line of code that causes the problems:

```
timesHit_txtview.setText(next.getTimesHit());
```

Like I mentioned before, I don't get any errors in eclipse. The First error I get from log cat is "Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception"

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

```
package com.whatever.main;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Next next = new Next();
TextView timesHit_txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    timesHit_txtview.setText(5);


    Button next_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent nextscreen_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Next.class);
            startActivityForResult(nextscreen_intent, 0);
        }

    });

}

}
```

Comment: Post logcat message. That helps in understanding the issue. My guess  here is next is null which is throwing Nullpointerexception.

Comment: The error you're speaking about occurs exactly at this line ?

Have your tried step by step debugging ?

Comment: Hmm... Just noticed something. Even when I replace the code with this:
'timesHit_txtview.setText("5");'
The app force closes. Should I post my entire "Main"?

Comment: Please do, otherwise we can't see what is going on

Comment: Well, from the edit I have to assume `timesHit_txtview` is null. At least show where that's acquired.

Comment: And please add the logcat showing the error stack trace

Comment: Sorry, I'm pretty new at this. What do you mean it is null? Didn't I just declare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to initialize a widget before the `onCreate()` call has been completed.

Initialize your TextView in the `onCreate()` method before you call `setText` on it, like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Next next;
TextView timesHit_txtview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    next = new Next(); // Initialize Next

    timesHit_txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2); // Initialize Widget
    timesHit_txtview.setText(5);


    Button next_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    next_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent nextscreen_intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Next.class);
            startActivityForResult(nextscreen_intent, 0);
        }

    });

}
```

In your current code, timesHit_txtview is null when you try to set a text for it, which makes you Activity crash.

Comment: Glad I could help! You know you can set your OnClickListener in the XML file, just use `android:onClick="handleClick"` and then just create a method with a matching name : `public void handleClick(View view) {}`

Comment: Thanks. As you can tell I'm still a novice. I appreciate your time.